# Crear gráfica de tipo Timeline mostrando el número de veces que se repite la fecha

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, tablas, charts

Tengo una duda a la hora de representar unos datos (ya sea Excel, Tableau, Power BI...). Pongo un ejemplo:

Supongamos que tengo una tabla de ítems con tan solo 3 campos, por ejemplo:

```
ID  Suministrador   Fecha recepción
--  -------------   ----------------------
1   A               01/08/2019
2   B       
3   C               01/09/2019
4   A               05/07/2019
5   A       
6   B               06/06/2019
```

Y quiero representar un gráfico de tipo línea del tiempo en la que muestre en el eje principal una linea del tiempo y los valores sean el número de “ítems recibidos” pudiendo segmentar por “suministrador”.

Una forma que se me ocurre es con una tabla auxiliar en la que tuviera un campo “Fecha” y rellenase un listado de fechas continuo y para cada una de ellas contase el número de “ítems recibidos”, quedando muchas filas vacías. El problema es que esto no me permitiría segmentar por “suministrador”.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo una tabla dinámica, y que cuentes, agrupando por meses, cuántos productos te ha proporcionado cada proveedor.

He simulado un conjunto de datos tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego he creado una tabla dinámica basada en ese conjunto de datos:

1. He llevado el campo FECHA a la sección de filas, y he agrupado por meses
2. El campo SUMINISTRADOR al área de columnas
3. El Campo ID está en la sección de valores, con operación RECUENTO

Y obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez creada la tabla dinámica, entonces puedes crear un gráfico dinámico basado en dicha tabla, y con 1 click obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te pueda servir de idea.